# How to tell if Spring Integration Inbound email adapter has started successfully other than assuming if no error was thrown

Tags: spring-integration

We're using SI for email integration and there is a requirement to set the Status of the started Adapter(s). I don't see any direct way of telling if the adapter such as Imap with poller has started without any issue other than assuming it did if no error event was thrown to the error-channel.

We've max tries in case of connection exception and then we don't know if & when it has recovered from that connection failure.

This is causing some difficulty in updating the real status of the started adapter.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Smart Poller feature](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#__smart_polling).

Create a subclass of the `AbstractMessageSourceAdvice`. If the `afterReceive()` method is called, it means the operation was successful (regardless of whether or not the poll actually resulted in a message).

Comment: Started successfully adapter has its `isRunning()` as `true`.

Comment: But that just indicates the poller is running, not whether or not the polls are successful.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. I can see the method getting called for pollers but then how to identify which Adapter, can I use header enricher in advice chain and would that be available in the subclass so that i can invoke the status on the right adpater.  Reagrding, ImapIdle hows it going to work as Artem pointed.

Comment: @ArtemBilan - he's not using the idle adapter: "...adapter such as Imap with poller ...". @sonu131in the `afterReceive()` method, the source argument is the `MessageSource`; you can identify it with `getComponentName()` (cast the source to a `NamedComponent`) which will be the adapter's bean name + `.source`. Yes, you can use a message builder in that method to add header(s) if you wish.

Comment: @GaryRussell , We're using all three types of available adapters including IMAP-IDLE.

Comment: @GaryRussell, Also, we can have multiple imaps running so trying to see if I can add a unique identifier the bean id for the adapter.

Comment: As I said, the message source gets the adapter's bean name (`id` + `.source` if using XML configuration). For the IMAP Idle adapter you can add an `ApplicationListener` to listen for `ImapIdleExceptionEvent` if the adapter `isRunning()` and you have no such events, all is well.

Comment: @GaryRussell, thank you. I'm not able to set the adapter bean id dynamically and as I shared we can have multiple copies of child context for the same adapter running at the same time. I tried setting this in the XML file "<int-mail:inbound-channel-adapter id="imapAdapter_${id}" and id set in the child context environment but spring container is not liking it.

Comment: No, you can't have variable bean names. You didn't mention you have multiple child contexts just that you have multiple adapters. You can put your advice bean in each child context and give it a unique property.